# command line Node.js program using Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-init

Problem: Node.js command line program doesn't run. 
I followed [this](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/08/writing-a-command-line-node-tool/) tutorial loosely.
I run OSX, and let's say the program is filesearch.js.

```
$ filesearch
```

Returns

```
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 1: /Applications: is a directory
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 2: Gruntfile.js: command not found
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 3: Gruntfile.js: command not found
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 4: Gruntfile.js: command not found
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ /usr/local/bin/filesearch: line 5: ` * Copyright (c) 2014 User Names'
```

It doesn't matter what code is in the program file, or what command line arguments i use, I get the same stdout every time.

I installed grunt and grunt-cli using

```
npm install grunt
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Also installed grunt-init and the [Node template](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-node)

```
npm grunt-init -g
```

and placed the template in ~/.grunt_init where it is found by grunt-init

Initialized the grunt directory with

```
grunt-init node
```

I included the line in the program file to enable running as Node:

```
#!usr/bin/env node
```

Also symlinked the program directory with:

```
npm link
```

Why doesn't the program run?

Answer (score 0):

Include the suffix to the end of it.

```
$ filesearch.js
```

EDIT:

Sorry this part below may be useless. But if necessary reinstall these components in the program directory.

Also install grunt via npm:

```
npm install grunt
```

Then do:

```
npm install grunt -g cli
```

Make sure you have navigated to the desired directory with the *cd* command on terminal.

Further documentation found here:
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started